How to calculate the limit of $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sqrt{2n^3-7n+21} - \sqrt{3n^3+1}}{\sqrt{5n^3-5n^2+n+41}-\sqrt{n^2+3n+1}}$
I am trying to calculate the limit of this expression: $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sqrt{2n^3-7n+21} - \sqrt{3n^3+1}}{\sqrt{5n^3-5n^2+n+41}-\sqrt{n^2+3n+1}}$, but i am not really sure how should i get started.
Is this a valid, good way to solve it?
$$\begin{align*}
& \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sqrt{2n^3-7n+21} - \sqrt{3n^3+1}}{\sqrt{5n^3-5n^2+n+41}-\sqrt{n^2+3n+1}} \\
&=\frac{\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt{2n^3-7n+21} - \sqrt{3n^3+1}}{\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt{5n^3-5n^2+n+41}-\sqrt{n^2+3n+1}} \\
&=
\frac{\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt{2n^3-7n+21} - \lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt{3n^3+1}}{\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt{5n^3-5n^2+n+41}-\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt{n^2+3n+1}}
\end{align*}$$

That gives you an expression of the form $\frac{\infty - \infty}{\infty - \infty}$, which is certainly not well-defined.

"Is this a valid, good way to solve it?" No.

Hint: Try dividing both the numerator and the denominator by $n^{3/2}$.

In such cases, the general method is to factor out the highest degree.
